# Matlab: Is there a quicker way to count the number of occurrences of a value in a vector?

Tags: matlab

Thanks in advance for the help

I am using the following to count the number of occurrences of the value x in a vector v

```
count = sum(v == x);
```

Is there anyway that I can decrease the time to count these occurrences?  Notice that v tends to be small; usually no more than 100 elements.  However, this operation occurs tens of thousands of times in my code and seems to be by far the most time consuming operation when analyzing my code using the profiler.  I've looked at the accumarray function but it appears that the approach I give above tends to be faster (at least the way I tried to use it).

Comment: Can you maybe write a bit more on how you call this snippet thousands of times? Is `v` always the same? are the `x` wildly different? Could you do multiple such comparisons at the same time?

Comment: v and x are different every time.  Additionally, only one comparison is done at a time.  I'm trying to build an iterative local search heuristic where count is part of the output of my objective function.  That is why it is called so often

Comment: You should give us more information. The time consuming part is not this operation itself sum(v==x), but the need to call it thousands of times (many loops i guess). Try to use as few loops as possible will make your code faster.

Comment: If your dimensions are not prohibitive, can you consider concatenating all `v`'s and all `x`'s to a single matrix and then perform `v==x` only once? Obviously then you have to sum by rows or columns, depending on whether you concatenate all `v`'s and `x`'s by rows or columns.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the rest of your code and the type of data, one possible way to approach this is to subtract `x` from `v` and count zeros instead. E.g.,

```
v = rand(200,1);
v(121) = v(3); % add some duplicates of v(3)
v(189) = v(3); % add some duplicates of v(3)
x = v(3);
count = numlel(v)-nnz(v-x);
```

Subtracting costs CPU-time but you might benefit from it in the end. Since I don't have your data I've just made a small test. You can test on your actual data to see whether it's something for you or not.

```
N = 100000; 
for k = 1:1
    v = randn(200,1);
    vy = zeros(size(v));
    v(121) = v(3);
    v(189) = v(3);
    x = v(3);

    t1=tic;
    for j = 1:N
        count1 = sum(v(:)==x);
    end
    t1s=toc(t1)/N;
    t2=tic;
    for j = 1:N % time the cost of subtraction prior to nnz()
        vy=v-x;
        count2 = numel(v)-nnz(vy);
    end
    t2s=toc(t2)/N;
    t3=tic;
    for j = 1:N % time the cost of subtraction within nnz()
        count3 = numel(v)-nnz(v-x);
    end
    t3s=toc(t3)/N;
    [count1 count2 count3]
    [t1s t2s t3s]
end


ans =

     3     3     3


ans =

   1.0e-05 *

    0.1496    0.1048    0.1222
```

You can see John D'Errico's answer [here](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/37227) about counting zeros.

Comment: Based on the tests I ran with this approach versus the one I am using, the approach I am using comes out to be about 1.2% faster.

Comment: Then the subtraction costs too much in your case, I guess. Since that's the case I second uPhone's suggestion; it's not this part of the code that's the "problem". Is it an option to port some of these calls to e.g. mex-code?

Comment: I can't port it (see my comment above about local iterative search), I guess I'll just have to deal with it.  Thanks for the suggestion tho!  I've up voted your answer

Comment: I thought of just porting the search, not the complete code. E.g. something as simple as the following [MEX-code](http://pastebin.com/h9z1aqwy)
and just call the function as ``count = foo(v(:),x);``. Not sure if you'd gain much, but could be worth a shot.